# Return the nth digit from division between two integers

Tags: c++

Is it possible to return the 100th decimal digit or so from the division of two integers? The reason I ask is because I'm trying to output the digits to the right of the decimal from the result of a fraction into an array of 1000 chars.

Here's my current function (with obvious rounding errors) if it helps:

```
char number[1000]; //to hold 1000 digits
for (short i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        number[i] = (char)fmod((numerator * pow(10, i + 1) / denominator), 10);
```

Comment: The floating point operations you're using won't go anywhere near 100 digits. You need to keep everything as integers throughout the whole process. Just do long division the way you learned it in school.

Comment: You sholud use some arbitrary precision arithmetic library like [this](https://gmplib.org/) to achive that, built in types have far less precision.

Comment: @Bob__ I was unable to find a tutorial on how to install or use GMP for Windows.

Comment: @MarkRansom How would an algorithm for that even work? Subtract the denominator from the remainder multiplied by 10, that becomes the new remainder, and repeat?

Comment: You can also use [Boost Multiprecision Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html). What IDE/compiler are you using?

Comment: @Larrimus I think you've got it, except you need to multiply the denominator by the new digit you've generated before you subtract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark Ransom stated - you have to do the long division.

For n decimals use:

```
inline char* function_name(const size_t digits, const int numerator, const int denominator)
{
    char *retVal(new char[digits]);
    int reminder(numerator%denominator);
    for(size_t i(digits); i>0; --i)
    {
        reminder *= 10;
        *retVal = '0' + reminder/denominator;
        ++retVal;
        reminder %= denominator;
    }
    return (retVal-digits);
}
```

For nth decimal use:

```
inline char function_name2(const size_t digit, const int numerator, const int denominator)
{
    int reminder(numerator%denominator);
    for(size_t i(digit); i>1; --i)
        reminder = (reminder*10)%denominator;
    return ('0' + (reminder*10/denominator));
}
```

(Sorry but I'm not good at naming functions)

To use them just do the following:

```
char *digits(function_name(31, x, y));
char digit(function_name2(31, x, y));
```

Hope it will help. Hope it doesn't need explanation (and don't forget to delete[] the array)

Comment: I don't plan on using a dynamic array.